# 5.1 Soundsystem - How to move LFE only to the Subwoofer?

Tags: sound, 20.04

I already had a number of issues to fix my sound system. I am currently running a Ubuntu 20.04 with pulseaudio, pulseeffects and alsamixer installed.

I added to my "default.pa" `load-module module-detect`, `load-module module-combine channels=6 channel_map=front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe` and to my daemon.conf

```
; enable-lfe-remixing = yes -- because this I was told is deprecated
remixing-produce-lfe = yes
remixing-consume-lfe = yes
```

As hardware I have a Sound Blaster X-Fi Titanium Series set to "Analog Surround 5.1".
The Gnome-Sound settings do whatever they like and as soon as I touch them they destroy the sound setting of the system.
I unmuted my Center/LFE in Alsamixer and now everything produces some kind of sound.

The sound is still horrible especially with bass-enhancer enabled in PulseEffects since my satellites try to produce bass sounds.

PulseEffects also seems to be disabled when it comes to read files correctly since it shows me that in "/etc/pulse/daemon.conf":

```
default-channel-map = front-left,front-left-of-center,front-center,front-right,front-right-of-center,rear-center
```

This line doesn't exist in the file. Therefore I explicitly added to this file and the one in "~/.config/pulse/":

```
default-sample-channels = 6
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe
```

Still after `pulseaudio -k` and a reboot of the system (and rechecking the files content) pulseeffects still is unable to read the file correctly. (Or whatever happens there)

Is there a way to only let the subwoofer produce the bass or maybe only let the subwoofer be affected by the bass enhancer since I am not sure how the sound will be when I remove the lfe from the satellites completely? (No idea where/how the split of the bass to the satellites is set and how to disable it)

Answer (score 2):

There is an option for `lfe-crossover-freq=` in `pulse-daemon.conf`.

Here's what `man pulse-daemon.conf` says about it:

```
   lfe-crossover-freq=  The  crossover  frequency  (in Hz) for the LFE filter. Set it to 0 to
   disable the LFE filter. Defaults to 0.
```

Instead of altering the settings under `/etc/`, I'd recommend that you copy these files to your user's home folder. (If you've already changed them, copy from your backup of the original files):

```bsh
cp /etc/pulse/daemon.conf ~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf
cp /etc/pulse/default.pa ~/.config/pulse/default.pa
```

Add the following line to `~/.config/pulse/default.pa`:

```
load-module module-combine channels=6 channel_map=front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe
```

Add (or uncomment) the following lines in `~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf`:

```
remixing-produce-lfe = yes
remixing-consume-lfe = yes
lfe-crossover-freq = value
```

Replace `value` with the desired crossover frequency (in Hz).  Frequencies below this value will be sent to the LFE channel.

Restart pulse with `pulseaudio -k`.