# 5.1 audio subwoofer not working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I have a problem with getting my subwoofer working on my 5.1 audio setup. Sound from speakers works no problem, but subwoofer refuses to make boom boom in 5.1 setting. When I switch to Analog Stereo Output (not 5.1) subwoofer works and makes boom boom. I have triple checked my audio cables and everything seems to be connected correctly.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and my motherboard is Asus Prime x570-Pro if that makes any difference. Cables are AUX from one side and RCA from the other. FR/FL is connected to Line Out on MB, Central/Subwoofer is connected to C/SUB and RR/RL to Rear Out. The speakers are "Genius SW-HF5.1 5200 HD" if it helps.

As other post suggested, modified `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`, uncommented `default-sample-channels = 2` and changed it to `default-sample-channels = 6`, but it did not help.

Also [including alsamixer and PulseAudio settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6MdQ.jpg). Not sure what else to include, so I will provide any other outputs as quickly as possible.

Could someone please help me with this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to change a few more settings.  Look at the answers on these questions: https://askubuntu.com/a/1296499 | https://askubuntu.com/a/1304054

Comment: Thank you very much @Nmath! Works like a charm without more tweaking.